# How to access data of another persisted model of loopback from remote method of one persisted model?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

```html
'use strict';
module.exports = function (City) {
City.GetCurrentPopulation = function (req) {
var population;
City.app.models.Pupulation.find({where{id:req.id}}, //This line //gives me an error that cannot read property 'find' of undefined 
function(req.res){
population=res.population;
});
response='Population for ' +req.cname ' is' +population;
req(null, response);
};
City.remoteMethod(
    'GetCurrentPopulation', {
      http: {
        path: '/GetCurrentPopulation',
        verb: 'GetCurrentPopulation'
      },
      returns: {
        arg: 'startdate',
        type: 'string'
      }
    }
  );
```

There is a model city and i want to access another model like "population.find(some filters)" How to do this?

I have a remote method written in city model. Where i am trying to access population record as

var countryp=population.find(where{id:4});

var currentpopulation=countryp.Totalpopulation;

It gives an error population.find is not a function.

Please suggest way to do this.

Comment: Is your question related to Loopback.js? Please ensure you have right set of tags for your question. Also, add information about environment you are using and/or libraries involved, otherwise it is difficult to guess what the question is about.

Comment: Yes it is related to loopback.js where in i am trying to make API from existing postgresql datasource.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Yes have added code snippet exactly similar to mine. Have omitted my original business  logic to avoid clutter in code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

City.app.models.Population can only work if you defined some relation between City & Population models. Otherwise it wont work that way.  If there is no relation to the other model.  You need to get a reference to the app object using

Try like this:

```
var app = require('../../server/server');
module.exports = function (City) {

var Population = app.models.Population;
City.GetCurrentPopulation = function(req) {
     Population.find({where{id:req.id}}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    } else {
        // do something here 
    });
}
```

You can refer to the documentation here [https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Working-with-LoopBack-objects.html#using-model-objects](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Working-with-LoopBack-objects.html)

Comment: Thanks you. var app = require('../../server/server'); was missing and creating issue.

Comment: Hi, Have added a remote hook for one method in similar way. There i am trying to access one model and insert a record into it there. Have added reference to that model in way mentioned above.  var app = require('../../server/server'); and var Population = app.models.Population; inside export function. On "Population.upsert()" it says can not read upsert of undefined.

Comment: try adding var Population = app.models.Population; statement inside the function like this
City.GetCurrentPopulation = function(req) {
     var Population = app.models.Population;
}

Comment: Thank you, It worked for me, would can you please help me around one more question? here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621993/how-to-get-auto-id-after-upsert-on-a-persisted-model-in-loopback

Comment: @Dyo The same am facing i want to access from one module to another but am getting an error. i want to get the filename in the persisted model is it possible to get the filename