# How to get auto Id after upsert on a persisted model in loopback?

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a some models generated from postgresql db using looback-connector postgresql. Id column of these models is a auto incremented integer column of postgresql db.

1) I have a remote method added on one of persisted models, where i perform simple update or insert(upsert.

```
 Car.CreateOrUpdateCar = function (carobj, req)     {
    Car.upsert(Carobj, function (err, Car) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            req(err, Car);
        }
    });
};
```

2) have  added a remote hook to execute after this remote method.

```
       Car.afterRemote('CreateOrUpdateCar', function (context, remoteMethodOutput, next) {
//Remaining code goes here
      next();
        });
```

3) I want to use **Id** of newly inserted row in step (1), in the remote hook mentioned in step (2)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about postgresql db. But Try it like this

```
    var carObj;
    Car.CreateOrUpdateCar = function (carobj, req)     {
    Car.upsert(Carobj, function (err, Car) {
        if (err)
          console.log(err);
        else {
          req(err, Car); // Your Car object contains final result after upserting along with Id
          carObj = Car;
        }
     });
   };
```

Now you can get id by using carObj.id and you can use it where ever you want. I hope this helps

Comment: As it goes to remote hook immediately after req(err, car). carobj stays "undefined" in the remote hook. Anyways car object itself dosent contain "id". As i am inserting a new record. I can either send {"id"=null} in inserting object or dont specify "id" key at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to generated id in remote hook like this :

```
 Car.afterRemote('CreateOrUpdateCar', function (context, remoteMethodOutput, next) {
  var genId = remoteMethodOutput.id || context.result.id;
      next();
        });
```

Comment: That expression was little diffrent in my case **remoteMethodOutput.records.__data.id || context.result.records.__data.id** Still genId comes undefined.  As i am inserting a new record. I can either send {"id"=null} in inserting object or dont specify "id" key at all. What happens on upsert, it returns me object same as it was inserted by me. If i dont add key "id" in inserting object, the object returned by upsert also does not have "id" in it. If i specify "id" as null it returns id as null.

Comment: @GaneshMahajan Have you checked `context.result.id`?

Comment: Yes, That is also undefined. Idinjection is set to false in my model. As i am using my own id column. is that making a difference?

Comment: @GaneshMahajan Yes of course. It's better to define your id like : `"id": {"type": "Number", "id": true, "generated": true}`

Comment: "id": {
      "type": "Number",
      "id": true,
      "required": false,
      "index": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 32,
      "scale": 0,
      "generated": true,
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "Id",
        "dataType": "integer",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 32,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "NO"
      }                                       this is how my id column is defined and still the behaiviour is same. Please suggest if any change in this.

Comment: @GaneshMahajan Actually `"required"` should be `true` bot not related to the issue. The last thing comes to my mind is that you set `id` as hidden properties

Comment: making required true gives me an validation error while creating new record. As i send it null or undefined. Can you please guide me or give some reference for setting id as hidden property?

Comment: Was this issue ever solved? Stuck at the same place. Just need the ID (auto generated) of a newly inserted record.

Comment: @Harshil Hey man, the same issue. Created a PR for that: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector/pull/146